# What URL to use with WebSockets on shared hosting?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am trying to configure WebSockets on my shared hosting account. I know that my account allows shared hosting, as I checked with their docs. I am using [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FduLSXEHLng&t=299s), which I have previously used on my local computer with localhost and it worked perfectly.

My approach is fairly straightforward:

The client code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("wss://<The shared hosting ip>:8082");
        
ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
    console.log("connected");
});
```

The server code:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8082 });

wss.on("connection", ws => {
    console.log("connected!");
})
```

The client never connects. I have switched out everything I can think of in terms of the shared hosting IP in the client code. I have simply used the ip with and without the port, the domain name with and without the the port, the domain name with the folder that the server is in with and without the port. It simply says,

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://<the URL>:8082' failed:
```

No matter what I try.

Comment: is port 8082 available for you? shared hosting (in my experience) means ports 80 and probably 443 are about the only incoming ports you have at your disposal

Comment: @Bravo I tried to change it to be on port 443 but got this error:
`Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443`

Comment: that would be because the http server has that open - without knowing anything about your hosting, I'd say the only way is to ask the host to open port 8082 for you - or, rather than "shared hosting" get yourself a VPS with full control